# Does Ruby have something similar to .=, like +=?

Tags: ruby

Since one can do:

```
a += 1
```

I was thinking whether one can also do something similar to:

```
a .= 1
```

The use case would be, for example, with ActiveRecord:

```
query = Model
query .= where(name: 'John') # instead of query = query.where(name: 'John')
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What's your planned use case for something like this?  You can overload operators in Ruby so you *could* do this if you wanted to, but it's unclear from this description why it'd make sense.  Nominally, invocation of methods is done so with tacit knowledge; this feels like it's masking that.  It feels different than the syntactic sugar for mathematical operators.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma: very common in builder-like objects. Line after line of `query = query.where(...)`

Comment: Thanks! @SergioTulentsev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, ruby does not have anything like this. Only certain "compound operators" are allowed by Ruby syntax and this operator is not among them.

However, there might be workarounds under specific circumstances (not this one, though). If, say, you had an array, then instead of

```
ary = ary.select { ... } if foo
ary = ary.select { ... } if bar
ary = ary.compact
```

you'd be able to do

```
ary.select! { ... } if foo
ary.select! { ... } if bar
ary.compact!
```

(*this can have unintended consequences, yes, because in-place mutation is dangerous in general. But in some cases it is desirable. Don't do it to shorten your code.*)

Comment: I'd word this more like "only certain 'compound operators' are allowable by Ruby syntax" since there's no reason `+=` couldn't have been used this way. The reason `.=` wouldn't work is because `.` isn't a function, no? Or am I over-simplifying a bit too much?

Comment: @DaveNewton Not only because it's not a function/method/message. The operator must also be recognized by the parser. This means no dynamic stuff (maybe this wasn't even a  requirement? Am I over-generalizing the problem here? :) )

Comment: Probably ;) But yes, I borked regarding "because it isn't a function" which obviously isn't the only reason :/

Answer (score 6):

Ruby is able to detect line continuations automatically:

```
query = Model
  .where(name: 'John')
  .select(:first_name)
```

This is equivalent to this (with the dots at the end):

```
query = Model.
  where(name: 'John').
  select(:first_name)
```

Note that due to the way lines are evaluated in IRB, only the second syntax (with the dots at the end of the line) works as intended there. With the first example, IRB would evaluate the line as soon as it sees the newline. In a Ruby script, both options work quite well.

There apply different style considerations here, with people having different opinions on which one is best.

Generally, this approach requires that the combined line is syntactically equivalent to a single line. You can't use inline conditions that way. This would thus be invalid syntax:

```
query = Model
  .where(name: 'John') if some_condition
  .select(:first_name)
```

If you require these conditions, it is just fine to assign intermediate results to a local variable as shown by Sergio Tulentsev in his answer. You'll often see this and it is not a code smell at all.

Comment: I strongly advocate for trailing dot convention of multiline chaining. The other way is just wrong! (REPL-friendliness is hard to overestimate)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Except that the period at the end throws off my Smalltalk brain.

Comment: Also, when adding a new chain on a new line, the code diff reads nicer with a leading dot.

Comment: Yes-yes, leading dot _looks_ a bit nicer, but you never know when you will want to paste it into a console. Utility trumps aesthetics here (IMHO, obviously)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev *q.e.d* regarding the style considerations :)